# Skip the host when pasword prompted in fabric

Tags: fabric

I am running fab task by using key based authentication. If any of host prompted for password, fabric should skip the host and should continue the job with next host.

I have tried with --abort-on-prompts , but this option stop the job. I want to continue the job.

Comment: can you provide more information about which version of python and fabric do you use?

Comment: @Peshmerge  python version : Python 2.7.6 and fabric version: Fabric 1.8.2